# Make [Traversal] a tag synonym of [Traverse] and [Traversing]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

The tags [traversal](/questions/tagged/traversal), [traverse](/questions/tagged/traverse) and [traversing](/questions/tagged/traversing) all refer to moving throughout some sort of data structure; should they be made synonyms?

Comment: It looks to me like these aren't really useful tags at all

Comment: I can see why having a traverse tag would be useful, but no reason for there to be three seperate ones.